# Задача сделать поиск по содержимому документов Word, PDF и д.р

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно сделать на сервере с использованием PHP/MySQL. Создание индексирования.

В голову первое пришло такое, через библиотеки открывать например файл noname.doc получать весь читабельный текст без картинок и остального мусора и записывать в MySQL под соответствующим названием файла. Далее при поиске делать уже классический поиск - text_index LIKE '%words words%'
Мне кажется, так получиться очень громоздко и может быть есть варианты по проще? Громоздко в плане того что, может быть есть варианты как то покомпактнее записывать вместо всего текста документа.

Что посоветуете для индексирования содержимого файлов? Библиотеки или свои теории.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

Конкретизируйте, пожалуйста, задачу. Суть в том, чтобы самому с нуля это разработать? Или использовать полностью готовое решение?

1. Если допустимо полностью готовое решение, то был такой проект Google Desktop Search. Прекрасно индексировал документы.
2. Для обработки текстов лучше подходят специализированные движки - elasticsearch, sphinxsearch итп. Интегрируйте их и все будет отлично